# WPF async void fun() для событий контролла. (MapCOntrol.WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, карты

Задача: Отмечаем чекбокс элементы и рисуем их на карте.

При нажатии на кнопку выполняется событие, где вызывается функция, в которой запускается цикл

```
public void DrawObjectTree()//функция
{
    foreach (var tb_head in itemPlHead.Children)//цикл
    {
        if (tb_head is Controls.CheckBox)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)tb_head;
            cb.IsChecked = true;//ставим галочки для списка чекбоксов
        }
    }
}
```

При отметке на чекбоксе возникает событие

```
async private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    paths.Add(new Path()){...};
    ...
    var t = await GetCoordAsync(_var, context, CancellationToken.None);
    MapPanel.SetLocation(paths[paths.Count - 1],new Location() { Latitude = t.lat, Longitude = t.lon });
    map.Children.Add(paths[paths.Count - 1]);//ошибка тут
}
```

Т.е. асинхронно находим координаты и рисуем paths на карте (MapControl.WPF).
Как находятся координаты, схематично

```
async Task<Coord> GetCoordAsync(var _var, context db, CancellationToken ct)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
    try
    {
        Coord result = db.GetCoord(_var);
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        return result ;
    }
    catch ...
    }, ct);
}
```

Если координату находить **синхронно**, то все корректно работает (кроме UI).
В таком виде ошибка
Указанный элемент Visual уже является дочерним по отношению к другому элементу Visual или корневому элементу CompositionTarget.

Насколько я понял причину, то это из-за того, что функция собития для чек-бокса у нас async и void, то есть внутри функции CheckBox_Checked как только попадается await тут же возвращается выполнение родительскому потоку. 
И начинается выполнятся функция для второго "рисунка".

```
map.Children.Add(paths[paths.Count - 1]);//ошибка тут, paths[] одинаково для первого "рисунка" и для второго. (Один отрисовывается нормально, после второго крашитmся). В синхронном варианте, для первого рисунка paths.Count=1 , для 2-го paths.Count=2 и т.д. В асинхронном у всех 1 - из-за этогО и ошибка вылетает
```

Comment: Запоминайте создаваемый Path в локальной переменной и забудьте про `paths.Count-1`

Comment: Вы правы! Сначала не понял Ваш ответ, думал вы имели ввиду сохранять счетчик в отдельной переменной.

Comment: Позвольте дать вам совет - если вы не уверен, что поняли, что означает комментарий или ответ просто уточните у автора ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока выполняется GetCoordAsync в paths могут быть добавлены новые элементы.
Ошибка в том, что после GetCoordAsync берется последний элемент из списка paths.
Нужно запоминать добавленный элемент и использовать его:

```
async private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var newPath = new Path{...};
    paths.Add(newPath);
    ...
    var t = await GetCoordAsync(_var, context, CancellationToken.None);
    MapPanel.SetLocation(newPath ,new Location() { Latitude = t.lat, Longitude = t.lon });
    map.Children.Add(newPath);
}
```